# django migration error message

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class customer(models.Model):
    # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    cstid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    age=models.IntegerField()
    mobile=models.IntegerField()

class doctor(models.Model):
    docid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Need autoincrement, unique and primary
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    regid = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="", blank=True)
    photo = models.CharField(
        max_length=35, default="", blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(default="")
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    qualifications = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(
        max_length=35, default="", blank=True)
    specialities = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="ENT", blank=True)
    fees = models.FloatField(default=300.0)
    displayfee = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    slotrange = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slotdurn = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    breakrange = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)
    slotsleft = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class appointment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    docid = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cstid = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    CstSlot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    SlotsAvailable = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Durn = models.IntegerField()
```

During migration, I get the following errors:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'cstid' to appointment without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>>
```

How can I fix these?

Comment: select option 2 and then give some value and change it afterwards

Answer (score 2):

When you are defining a model field. By default `null=False`. So if null is prohibited you have to set default value. Or you have to set `null=True`.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Choose the `option 1` while migrating, and provide some integer value that represents `PK` of **existing** customer
**Option 2**
Change your `models.py` as any of the following method
**a) .** add **`null=True`** to model

```
class appointment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    docid = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cstid = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    CstSlot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    SlotsAvailable = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Durn = models.IntegerField()
```

**b) .** add **`default=some_customer_id`** to model

```
class appointment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    docid = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cstid = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=1)
    CstSlot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    SlotsAvailable = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Durn = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `cstid` with:

```
cstid = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```